# Update javafx scene : listening to stringproperty and binding

Tags: javafx, event-handling, listener, event-listener, scene

I need to make a game for one of my java courses (I have some basic knowledge about object oriented programming in java otherwise) : I created a javaFX scene (that goes on a swing frame, using JFXFrame) on **a class that's my View**, then I have two other classes : **one that handles the Game**, and **the other for creating Player** objects.

Now, when the game is running, **players take turns, and I'd like to show the name of the currentPlayer** : I added that attribute to my Game class, and the name of a Player is SimpleStringProperty, because I read it is easier to use listeners with it.

Problem is: I don't get how to do that... I am sorry, my question might seem stupid, but I have really been trying for two weeks to ***use listeners*** in all sorts of ways, and it doesn't do a thing: **my javaFX scene doesn't get updated** (we don't see the change of the currentPlayer's name).
I read about *binding*, thought it might help, but I don't know how to use that either.

Any ideas or explanations ? Thanks a lot !

*Here's what my code looks like :*

// THE VIEW

```
public class TestView {
    protected static Game game = new Game("Random Game");
    protected static BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    protected static GridPane grilleHaut = new GridPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TestView.initialisation();
        }
    });
    game.runSomething();
}

public static void initialisation() {
    JFrame mainSwingFrame = new JFrame("Game");
    JFXPanel mainFXFrame = new JFXPanel();
    mainSwingFrame.add(mainFXFrame);
    mainSwingFrame.setSize(1200, 900);
    mainSwingFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainSwingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { initFX(mainFXFrame);}
    }  );
}

public static void initFX(JFXPanel frameFX) {
    Scene scene = newScene();
    frameFX.setScene(scene);
}

public static Scene newScene() {
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.LIGHTGOLDENRODYELLOW);

    Text gameName = new Text(game.name);
    grilleHaut.add(gameName, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(gameName, 0, 0, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.TOP);

    Text turn = new Text("It's " + game.currentPlayer.getName() + "'s turn to play.");
    game.currentPlayer.name.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        turn.setText("C'est au tour de : " + newValue);
    });
    game.currentPlayer.name.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> o,String oldv,String newv) {
            turn.setText("It's time to play for : " + newv);
            System.out.println("accessed on TestView.");
        }
    });

    grilleHaut.add(turn, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(turn, 0, 1, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(grilleHaut, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
    root.setTop(grilleHaut);

    return(scene);
}
```

}

// A GAME

```
class Game {
String name;
Player p1 = new Player("Person 1");
Player p2 = new Player("Human 2");
Player currentPlayer;

public Game(String n) {
    name=n;
    currentPlayer = p1;
}

public void runSomething() {
    //here goes code to run a game
    System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName());
    currentPlayer = p2; //at some point in the game, it's p2's time to play
    String pressToContinue; Scanner ptc = new Scanner(System.in); pressToContinue = ptc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName());
    currentPlayer = p1; //and then p1's again
    String pressToContinue2; Scanner ptc2 = new Scanner(System.in); pressToContinue2 = ptc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName());
}
```

}

// PLAYERS

```
class Player {
protected StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
public Player(String n) { 
    name.setValue(n); 
    name.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> o,String oldv,String newv) {
            Text turn = new Text("It's time to play for : " + newv);
            TestView.grilleHaut.add(turn, 0, 1);
            System.out.println("accessed on Player.");
        }
    });}
public String getName() { return name.getValue(); }
```

}

Comment: on  first sight your setup is upside down: the model - Player - must not have a reference to the view. instead let the model have observalble state and let the view listen to changes

Comment: It seems to be the player that changes, not the player's name. `newScene` adds a listener to the `name` property of the initial player though. You probably should use a `ObjectProperty<Player>` and make the `name` of a player a constant. (If you want to allow for player name changes, simply create a binding on a change of that property.)